# How can I use a variable of one <script> in another <script> in javascript?

Tags: javascript, variables, global

How can I use a variable of one  in another  in javascript?

Answer (score 17):

If the two script tags are on the same page, any variable declared outside of the scope of a function is global to the page.

Answer (score 10):

Make it [global](http://snook.ca/archives/javascript/global_variable/);

script1.js

```
 var foobar = "O HAI";
```

script2.js

```
  alert(foobar);
```

Comment: I assume all the downvotes here are because we didn't say "Don't use global variables"?  Or some other reason?

Answer (score 6):

If the two script tags are on the same page, any variable declared outside of the scope of a function is global to the page. However, it does matter which script is loaded first for some applications.

Answer (score 0):

When you declared a variable inside a `<script>` , you can access it anywhere simply by using this:

```
var myValue= window.yourProperty;
```

Comment: @andreas I edited answer. It was too summery, thanks for notice.